# Will MVC2 application run on MVC3 host server?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I have application wirtten in MVC2. In the host server is installed MVC3 framework. Will my application run in this host server or I need to install also(or maybe instead) MVC2?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have ASP.NET MVC 2 installed on the server (System.Web.Mvc, V2.0.0.0 assembly). You can also [bin-deploy ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx).

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 3 shouldn't support down?

Comment: @theateist, no, ASP.NET MVC 3 uses a different version of the System.Web.Mvc assembly.